# Creating a shape file from a bounding box coordinates list

Tags: python, gis, shapefile

There is already few existing questions about this topic, but I unfortunately did not find something that could fix my problem.

I have a point Lat, Long coordinate i.e. Lat= 10 and Long = 10. I want to create a shape file of a 0.5 degree bounding box around this point, so the bounding box should be as follow:

1. minimum Long= 9.75
2. minimum Lat = 9.75
3. maximum Long = 10.25
4. maximum Lat = 10.25

Does anyone knows how to do that in Python?

Comment: To create shape file you can use [pyshp](https://pypi.org/project/pyshp/) module from pip. See [module homepage](https://github.com/GeospatialPython/pyshp) for details.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here's one way to do it using shapely, geopandas and pandas:

```
import geopandas as gpd
import pandas as pd
from shapely.geometry import Polygon


def bbox(lat,lng, margin):                                                                                                                  
    return Polygon([[lng-margin, lat-margin],[lng-margin, lat+margin],
    [lng+margin,lat+margin],[lng+margin,lat-margin]])

gpd.GeoDataFrame(pd.DataFrame(['p1'], columns = ['geom']),
     crs = {'init':'epsg:4326'},
     geometry = [bbox(10,10, 0.25)]).to_file('poly.shp')
```

Answer (score 5):

I want to enchance Bruno Carballo's code. I hope it will easier for you

```
    import geopandas as gpd
    import pandas as pd
    from shapely.geometry import Polygon

    # function to return polygon
    def bbox(long0, lat0, lat1, long1):
        return Polygon([[long0, lat0],
                        [long1,lat0],
                        [long1,lat1],
                        [long0, lat1]])

    test = bbox(9.75, 9.75, 10.25, 10.25)

    gpd.GeoDataFrame(pd.DataFrame(['p1'], columns = ['geom']),
         crs = {'init':'epsg:4326'},
         geometry = [test]).to_file('poly.shp')
```

Answer (score 0):

And here is an implementation of Bruno Carballo's answer that applies it to en entire DataFrame:

```
import geopandas as gpd
import pandas as pd
from shapely.geometry import Polygon

# function to return polygon
def bbox(vec):
    long0, lat0, lat1, long1 = vec[0], vec[1], vec[2], vec[3]
    return Polygon([[long0, lat0],
                    [long0,lat1],
                    [long1,lat1],
                    [long1, lat0]])

def extentPolygon(df):
    return(
        pd.DataFrame({'geometry' : df[['ext_min_x','ext_min_y','ext_max_y','ext_max_x']].apply(bbox, axis = 1)})
    )


df = pd.DataFrame({'ext_min_x' : [9.75, 9.78], 'ext_max_x' : [10.25, 10.28], 
                    'ext_min_y' : [9.75, 9.78],  'ext_max_y' : [10.25, 10.28]})
df = extentPolygon(df)
```

After which you can easily turn the resulting DataFrame into a GeoDataFrame:

```
df_gp = gdp.GeoDataFrame(df)
```