# CDO to process my NETCDF files (average of a grid) using UBUNTU

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04, cdo-climate

I have a netcdf file located here `https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Ok2tVD_iCXe93Q1HYGv1jtyaTIc7wY2N/view?usp=sharing` which has monthly timesteps downloaded from

```
https://cds.climate.copernicus.eu/
```

I would like to get the average monthly of only one grid (say `lat 20 and 25 then longitude 120 and 125`).

I have no idea how to use and even upload my `.nc` file/s using CDO (I just installed UBUNTU app in my PC and I will start from there).

Anyone who can help me or direct me how to proceed with this stuff?

PS. In the file (see google drive link), the variable is `cloud cover`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Calculate variables mean in a selective area , in gridded netCDF file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22427954/calculate-variables-mean-in-a-selective-area-in-gridded-netcdf-file)

Comment: check out the linked page for solutions, I also posted some videos on this topic on my youtube channel "climateunboxed" in case that helps.